# "Speaking of which" vs "Speaking of such"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

I guess some context is in order so, suppose two people were talking about smart-phones and suddenly one of them wants to talk about something somewhat related, like a computer. Is it ok (or grammatically correct) to say "speaking of such..." in this case?

Comment: I would say "yes". It is less specific than "speaking of which", which you would probably only use if referring to smart phones, or even the specific smart phone you were discussing.

Comment: I assume you do not mean the determiner usage "speaking of such matters" etc. The use of the ellipsis is ambiguous. Most hits on a Google search for "speaking of such" involve the determiner usage, but there is the odd pronoun usage.

Comment: "Speaking of which" would be the norm, but "speaking of such" would be possible, at least informally. It may be best to analyse this "such" as a 'fused modifier-head' construction where the adjective "such" functions at the same time as modifier and head. We understand it to mean "such things".